# How to get keys and count of each key from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, lodash

I am trying to get the expected results below, but I am struggling. What is the best way to do it?

```js
const data = [{
    name: 'Dave',
    country: 'England',
    color: 'Brown'
  },
  {
    name: 'Dave',
    country: 'England',
    color: 'white'
  },
  {
    name: 'Cae',
    country: 'USA',
    color: 'white'
  },
  {
    name: 'Dave',
    country: 'England',
    color: 'Red'
  },
  {
    name: 'Cae',
    country: 'USA',
    color: 'Yellow'
  },
  {
    name: 'Dave',
    country: 'England',
    color: 'white'
  },
  {
    name: 'Manuel',
    country: 'USA',
    color: 'Red'
  },
  {
    name: 'Dave',
    country: 'England',
    color: 'white'
  }
];


// Tentative:

(function getDataForName() {
  count = 0;
  nameL = [];
  nameCount = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (nameL.indexOf(data[i].name) === -1) {
      nameL.push(data[i].name);
      count++;
    }
    nameCount.push(count);
  }
  console.log(nameL);
  console.log(nameCount);
})()
```

Expected Results:

```
nameL = ['Dave', 'Cae', 'Manuel'];
nameCount = [4, 2, 1];
```

Comment: Is this a learning exercise or just need a snippet that works?  chrisz answer works, but might be confusing to a learner

Comment: Remember to pick your answer carefully so others see your problem was solved. If you have any questions regarding any of the answers given, feel free to ask in the comments of that answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Lodash you can use `countBy` method to get one object and then you can use `keys` and `values` methods on that object.

```js
const data = [{name: 'Dave', country: 'England', color: 'Brown'},{name: 'Dave', country: 'England', color: 'white'},{name: 'Cae', country: 'USA', color: 'white'},{name: 'Dave', country: 'England', color: 'Red'},{name: 'Cae', country: 'USA', color: 'Yellow'},{name: 'Dave', country: 'England', color: 'white'},{name: 'Manuel', country: 'USA', color: 'Red'},{name: 'Dave', country: 'England', color: 'white'}]

const result = _.countBy(data, 'name')
const names = _.keys(result);
const count = _.values(result);

console.log(names);
console.log(count)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You have an elegant solution using vanilla ES6?

Comment: @connexo that's not vallina JS ES6

Answer (score 2):

How does this work for you? [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) just keeps calling this callback on the array while passing in the previous values.

```js
const data = [{name: 'Dave', country: 'England', color: 'Brown'},{name: 'Dave', country: 'England', color: 'white'},{name: 'Cae', country: 'USA', color: 'white'},{name: 'Dave', country: 'England', color: 'Red'},{name: 'Cae', country: 'USA', color: 'Yellow'},{name: 'Dave', country: 'England', color: 'white'},{name: 'Manuel', country: 'USA', color: 'Red'},{name: 'Dave', country: 'England', color: 'white'}];

x = data.reduce(function(sums,entry){
   sums[entry.name] = (sums[entry.name] || 0) + 1;
   return sums;
},{});

console.log(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

another way:

```
const [nameL, nameCount] = _.chain(data)
    .groupBy('name')
    .mapValues(_.size)
    .toPairs()
    .thru(_.spread(_.zip))
    .value();
```

Comment: You can replace the `.groupBy()` and `.mapValues()` pair with a single `countBy('name')` call. Additionally, you don't need to use the explicit chain method, `_.chain(data)`, you can safely use the implicit chain method, `_(data)`, in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Use the function `forEach` along with functions `Object.keys` and `Object.values`.

```js
const data = [    {name: 'Dave', country: 'England', color: 'Brown'},    {name: 'Dave', country: 'England', color: 'white'},    {name: 'Cae', country: 'USA', color: 'white'},    {name: 'Dave', country: 'England', color: 'Red'},    {name: 'Cae', country: 'USA', color: 'Yellow'},    {name: 'Dave', country: 'England', color: 'white'},    {name: 'Manuel', country: 'USA', color: 'Red'},    {name: 'Dave', country: 'England', color: 'white'}    ],
      a = {};

data.forEach((c) => a[c.name] = (a[c.name] || 0) + 1);

console.log(JSON.stringify(Object.keys(a)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(Object.values(a)));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This does it without any external libraries:

```js
const data=[{name:'Dave',country:'England',color:'Brown'},{name:'Dave',country:'England',color:'white'},{name:'Cae',country:'USA',color:'white'},{name:'Dave',country:'England',color:'Red'},{name:'Cae',country:'USA',color:'Yellow'},{name:'Dave',country:'England',color:'white'},{name:'Manuel',country:'USA',color:'Red'},{name:'Dave',country:'England',color:'white'}];

const result = data.reduce(function(count, entry){
   count[entry.name] = count[entry.name] ? count[entry.name] + 1 : 1;
   return count;
},{});

console.log(Object.keys(result));
console.log(Object.values(result));
```